# How to globally listen to bubbled events in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In web, I might do this:

```
<div onClick="console.log">
   <button onClick="window.handleClickOne" />
   <button onClick="window.handleClickTwo" />
</div>
```

And `console.log` would run one the bubbled event.

This doesnt work in react-native (for starters react-native `onPress` is only on `TouchableX`'s).

I was wondering if there was an equivalent in react-native?

Comment: Did u read the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button)?

Comment: Oh Im not asking about the API of Button. I am asking about the event system: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles and ways to replicate global listening in RN

Comment: you mean global event listeners, with `addEventListener` and etc? take a look at [this](https://github.com/meinto/react-native-event-listeners)